# Debian: You need to load the kernel first

Tags: linux, boot, debian

Recently I upgraded my Debian box to version 7.7. After reboot the following error occurs:

```
Loading Linux 3.2.0-4-amd646 ...
error: cannot read the Linux header.
Loading initial ramdisk ...
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, obviously your kernel can’t be read. What boot loader (and version) are you using? Do you have access to rescue media?

Comment: Bootloader is GRUB 1.99. I have access to Live Debian on USB disk.

Comment: The system is installed on 3TB disk.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to agtoever's answer:
Note that the last step of the cited Ubuntu guide is different for Debian:

```
apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-flavour
```

where flavour could be like amd64, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot from a LiveUSB and chroot to your Debian that's on the harddisk. Next, you can repair GRUB and/or the boot directory.

[This Ask Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130281/how-to-restore-boot-folder) explains it all very well.

*Don't forget to make a backup **before** you mess with partitions, GRUB and /boot directories.*